# Python Port Scanner with arg parser doesn't properly take multiple arguments

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to update some code from a great albeit dated book called "Violent Python." many of the examples used the deprecated optparse library and I have easily switched to argparse in MOST examples, however, my modified code doesn't work for this particular script IF I use more than one port argument. I became so frustrated I attempted to use the original example, but that code does not work AT ALL.

What works...

```
python portScan.py -H ipaddress -p 21

[+] Scan results for: (banner)
[-]21/tcp closed for port
```

What DOESN'T work...

```
python portScan.py -H ipaddress -p 21, 22

usage: usage%prog -H  <target host> -p <target port> [-h] [-H TGTHOST]
                                                 [-p [TGTPORT [TGTPORT ...]]]
usage%prog -H  <target host> -p <target port>: error: argument -p/--tgtPort:   invalid int value: '21,'
```

I realize this is because argparse takes multiple values for one argument and turns them into a list, but I have tried multiple methods for mapping the list into integer values. They all fail.

Here's my code below...

```
import argparse
from socket import *
from threading import *

screenLock = Semaphore(value=1)
def connScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
    try:
        connSkt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        connSkt.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
        connSkt.send('ViolentPython\r\n')
        results = connSkt.recv(100)
        screenLock.acquire()
        print '[+]%d/tcp open for port '% tgtPort #+ str(tgtPort)
        print '[+] ' + str(results)
    except:
        screenLock.acquire()
        print '[-]%d/tcp closed for port '% tgtPort #+ str(tgtPort)
    finally:
        screenLock.release()
        connSkt.close()
def portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts):
    try:
        tgtIP = gethostbyname(tgtHost)
    except:
        print "[-] Cannot resolve '%s': Unknown host"%tgtHost
        return
    try:
        tgtName = gethostbyaddr(tgtIP)
        print '\n[+] Scan results for: ' + tgtName[0]
    except:
        print '\n[+] Scan Results for: ' + tgtIP
        setdefaulttimeout(1)
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, tgtPort))
        t.start() 
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("usage%prog " "-H  <target host> -p <target port>")
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--tgtHost', help='specify target host')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--tgtPort', nargs= '*', type=int, help='specify target port')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    tgtHost = args.tgtHost
    tgtPorts = args.tgtPort #str(args.tgtPort).split(',')
    if (tgtHost == None) | (tgtPorts == None):
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code. You know most of the time we don't use `,` to seperate arg values. Instead, we use space:

```
>python port_scanner.py -H 127.0.0.1 -p 21 22

[+] Scan results for: localhost
[-]21/tcp closed for port
[-]22/tcp closed for port
```

Comment: Doh! that was indeed the issue. Thanks Skyline when I get my rep up i'll be sure to answer this as useful.